# I can't see DJVU thumbnails in Xubuntu (13.10)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, evince, djvu

So the problem is as follows:

I downloaded a certain number of Djvu books. When I open the location in Thunar, no thumbnail is shown. "Show thumbnails" option in Desktop Settings is enabled. PDF files are previewed correctly, and in `/usr/share/evince-thumbnailer/` `image/vnd.djvu`exists as an option. I tried adding additional types of djvu mime codes to the thumbnailer desktop file but no work! Tried to manually run `evince-thumbnailer $i $o` on a file gave the correct output. I also tried to get the available ARCH extension which is alike the mentioned `evice-thumbnailer` command (almost exact).

If you need any additional information, I would like to solve this since on all 4 machines I use Xfce.

Comment: What about Nautilus. Does it work in it?

Comment: It does. Just installed nautilus in XFCE. It shows the preview of DJVU file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nautilus instead of Thunar to preview DJVU thumbnails in Xubuntu. Nautilus provides roughly the same functionality set as Thunar, and should work without issues under Xfce.

If however you absolutely want to use Thunar for this, then you should check whether you have [tumbler](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/tumbler) installed.

Comment: Using Nautilus is not an option. On the other side I have tumbler installed, with the default configuration.

Comment: Then it is quite possible that this is a bug in Tumbler, and it should be reported at https://bugzilla.xfce.org/ .

Comment: If you check the [tumbler roadmap](http://wiki.xfce.org/releng/4.10/roadmap/tumbler), you will notice that it doesn't talk of either `djvu` or `evince-thumbnailer`. Also, see this relevant thread on the forums that yielded no answers: [Thunar (tumbler) djvu support ?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166438).